# Simplify Community Bulletin widget

Tags: script, style, stylish

This *Stylish* script:

- Hides the recently added bold category titles;
- Removes post vote counts;
- Reduces space used by widget.

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com") {
  .bulletin-title, .related hr, 
  .bulletin-item-type   { display:none !important; }
  .bulletin-item-content { width: 100% !important; }
}
```

And here's an example from Aviation and Movies & TV sites:

[image]

It's set to only work on beta sites, but you can alter the domain name to work with other sites of the network.